# Pinna iPhone Construction

Tags: iphone, field-recording, modification

A variety of mics has to be the equivalent to the swiss army knife of field recording.

Some very unique and useful recordings have come from iPhone microphones. Whether it be some random ambience, a funny noisemaker in a toy shop, or any spur of the moment capture ...

I was wondering if anyone had actually made or found a pinna/cone/etc like structure to successfully enhance, focus, or modify in a desirable way the input to the phone? I have actually cupped my hand around the microphone and had greater focus. Also, placing the phone on a resonant structure coupled with the sound source has allowed me to capture more bass in a sound.

Any thoughts?

---

Just found these - not much for non mic devices but still some cool products:

Use this in conjunction with this to use any mic (or using a T or Phantom box additionally) http://www.kvconnection.com/product-p/009-541.htm / http://www.kvconnection.com/product-p/km-iphone-2trs.htm

Cardioid Condensor Mic - http://www.bluemic.com/mikey_for_ipod/

Quarter Inch Line Input - http://www.ikmultimedia.com/irig/features/

SoundClip for iPhone 3G (VCProd's product suggestion for audio output) Would love a 4 version of this!
http://tenonedesign.com/soundclip.php

Small mic attachment - http://touchmic.com/products-page/view-all-products/touchmic-mitymic---voice-recording-and-interview-mic/

Interesting lil array of products.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could do any number of things to alter the mic on the iPhone (like wrap it in foil), but I doubt any of them would improve the sound.  I'd think I'd rather have a clean version to alter in editing than put a device on that turns it in to a roll of the dice on what I'll actually get out.

The only interesting passive devices I've seen for the iPhone are on the output side - little wooden boxes with holes you can slide the phone in to and amplify the sound a little bit.

Comment: @VCProd 'Point being getting a better recording from the phone. Maybe even make it into a more directional mic. Either way, it would be a device to allow you to achieve a specific outcome every time you use it - not a roll of the dice kind of attachment. Ill hit ya up if I find anything!